# How to restart liquidslider on tab click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, slideshow

I have a page with multiple sliders - each within its own tab. I'd like for the sliders to start over if a user leaves a tab and then returns.

Dev link:  http://dev.triciafrancis.com/mbrstudios/case-studies/

Here is the code I'm using for liquidslider and tabs:

```
//Use liquid slider to setup slides within tabbed content
    $('#tabs .tab .liquid-slider').liquidSlider({
        preloader: true,
        autoHeight: false,  
        dynamicTabs: true,
        dynamicTabsHtml: true,
        dynamicTabsAlign: 'center',
        dynamicTabsPosition: 'bottom',
        panelTitleSelector: '.slide-nav',
        dynamicArrows: true,
        dynamicArrowsGraphical: true,
        hideSideArrows: true,  
        hoverArrows: false, 
        hoverArrowDuration: 250,
        autoSlide: true,
        continuous: true,  
        autoSlideInterval: 5000,
        autoSlideDirection: 'right',
        slideEaseFunction: 'easeOutCirc',
        heightEaseFunction: 'easeOutCirc'
    });
    //Set transitions for tab changes and activate first tab
    $('.sub-menu a:visible').on('click', function(e)  {   
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.sub-menu a.active').removeClass('active');
        $('.tab:visible').hide();
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        $(this.hash).fadeIn('slow'); 
        if($('.ls-nav:visible a').length < 2) {
            $('.ls-wrapper:visible').addClass('single-slide');
        };
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }).filter(':first').click();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I emailed the plugin author and got the following feedback:

> I would use the API to control the sliders inside. There are a few
>   things you could do...
>
> var api = $.data( $('#slider')[0], 'liquidSlider');
>
> This will store the slider as an object and give you access to its
>   functions.
>
> api.setNextPanel(1)
>
> This will set the panel to the first one. So you would have to set up
>   an event that sets all the sliders to the first panel based on the
>   action you desire. I'm assuming you would want to use the
>   pretransition function in the parent slider.
>
> Here is some more information: 
>   https://kevinbatdorf.github.io/liquidslider/examples/page1.html#advanced-controls

I applied this method and initially could only get it to work on the slideshow within  the first tab.  So I had to restructure the selector for liquidslider and apply the the technique to each tab.  There's probably a more efficient way, but this is what I got to work:

```
//Use liquid slider to setup slides within tabbed content
    $('#tab1-images, #tab2-images, #tab3-images, #tab4-images').liquidSlider({
        preloader: true,
        autoHeight: false,  
        dynamicTabs: true,
        dynamicTabsHtml: true,
        dynamicTabsAlign: 'center',
        dynamicTabsPosition: 'bottom',
        panelTitleSelector: '.slide-nav',
        dynamicArrows: true,
        dynamicArrowsGraphical: true,
        hideSideArrows: true,  
        hoverArrows: false, 
        hoverArrowDuration: 250,
        autoSlide: true,
        continuous: true,  
        autoSlideInterval: 5000,
        autoSlideDirection: 'right',
        slideEaseFunction: 'easeOutCirc',
        heightEaseFunction: 'easeOutCirc'
    });
    //Reset slideshows to first image on tab click
    $('.sub-menu li:nth-child(1n) a').on('click', function()  { 
        var tabImages = '#tab1-images';
        if($(tabImages).length) {
            var api = $.data( $(tabImages)[0], 'liquidSlider');
            api.setNextPanel(0);
        }
    })
    $('.sub-menu li:nth-child(2n) a').on('click', function()  { 
        var tabImages = '#tab2-images';
        if($(tabImages).length) {
            var api = $.data( $(tabImages)[0], 'liquidSlider');
            api.setNextPanel(0);
        }
    })
    $('.sub-menu li:nth-child(3n) a').on('click', function()  { 
        var tabImages = '#tab3-images';
        if($(tabImages).length) {
            var api = $.data( $(tabImages)[0], 'liquidSlider');
            api.setNextPanel(0);
        }
    })
    $('.sub-menu li:nth-child(4n) a').on('click', function()  { 
        var tabImages = '#tab4-images';
        if($(tabImages).length) {
            var api = $.data( $(tabImages)[0], 'liquidSlider');
            api.setNextPanel(0);
        }
    })
    //Set transitions for tab changes and activate first tab
    $('.sub-menu a:visible').on('click', function(e)  {  
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.sub-menu a.active').removeClass('active');
        $('.tab:visible').hide();
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        $(this.hash).fadeIn('slow');
        //Add class to single-image slides, so navigation elements can be hidden with css
        if($('.ls-nav:visible a').length < 2) {
            $('.ls-wrapper:visible').addClass('single-slide');
        };
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }).filter(':first').click();
```